# How to create an embed that allows switching between multiple code snippets via a button

Tags: embed, code-snippets, notion

I wish to create embeds in notion to manage and share my code snippets.
However, some code snippets serve the same purpose. For example, a sorting algorithm can be written in multiple programming languages, or implemented in different ways (quick sort and merge sort).

I want these code snippets that serve the same purpose to be presented in single embed/window and toggled as needed.

I found that leetcode playground provides a similar feature to create code snippet embeds as follows:
[embed generated by leetcode playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQffV.png)

Unfortunately, this feature provided by the **plus plan** can only be switched among multiple programming languages. Besides, I need to pay for features I don't need, which seems too expensive.

What I'm wondering is if there are existing tools for this. If useful, I'd be happy to pay for this. If not, how can I achieve this purpose.

I'm looking forward to your answer! Thanks!